# Bundling is creating collisions when JavaScript is minified

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle

I have a JavaScript file with this simplified form:

```
var MainObj = (function($) {
    function func1() {}  // <-- minification renames to c()
    function func2() {
        function func3() {}  // <- minification renames to c()
        func1();   // <-- minification calls c() and hits func3 instead of func1
    }
}
```

I added this JavaScript file to a ScriptBundle in ASP.NET and the resulting minified file had a collision. Both `func1` and `func3` were renamed to the same function name `c`. So in the call to `func1` I ended up calling `func3` instead.

I fixed this issue by explicitly calling `MainObj.func1()`. Short of refactoring all of our code how do we tell the bundler not to create this kind of collision?

I looked at [Microsoft's page on bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#minification) and saw no options for configuring the minification.

Answer (score 0):

Configure bundle optimization by using 
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations

Comment: Thanks. We have code in place for doing this in debug scenarios. And actually that is part of the problem. The minification is set to only occur in production so this bug slipped through to production precisely because it is caused by the minification process.